# Why isn't my editor highlighting all of my PHP code?

Tags: php, syntax-highlighting

In my code editor, it normally displays PHP code in bold blue print. I'm finding some of my code is not showing up as bold blue print. Can someone please look at the code below and tell me if I'm doing something wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
    <td class="hr"><?php echo htmlspecialchars("payroll number")."&nbsp;" ?></td>
    <td class="dr"><input type="text" name="GevityNo" maxlength="10" value="<?php echo str_replace('"', '&quot;', trim($row["GevityNo"])) ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="hr"><?php echo htmlspecialchars("employee name")."&nbsp;" ?></td>
    <td class="dr"><textarea cols="25" rows="1" name="employee_name" maxlength="75"><?php echo str_replace('"', '&quot;', trim($row["employee_name"])) ?></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="hr"><?php echo htmlspecialchars("Sex")."&nbsp;" ?></td>
    <td class="dr"><select name="Sex">
    <option value=""></option>
    <?php
        $lookupvalues = array("male","female");
        reset($lookupvalues);
        foreach($lookupvalues as $val){
            $caption = $val;
            if ($row["Sex"] == $val) {$selstr = " selected"; } else {$selstr = ""; }
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $val ?>"<?php echo $selstr ?>><?php echo $caption ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>
</td>
```

Comment: I would be confused if I were your editor, too. Use proper code formatting and indenting and you won't need to ask yourself if it is correct.

Comment: @KAH: please, don't touch code anymore. It was fixed at least 3 times by now

Answer (score 5):

```
$ cat > /home/tkn/tmp/foo.php
  ... snip ...
^C
$ php -l /home/tkn/tmp/foo.php 
No syntax errors detected in /home/tkn/tmp/foo.php
```

So, yes it's valid php code. Get a better editor.

Answer (score 1):

The *syntax-highlighting* is part of the code editor you are using. If your code is working fine, there is no problem then.

Answer (score 0):

Usually these problems are related with wrongly escaped \". Without seeing the whole code is hard to say.

Anyway, double check that this part of your code is ok:

```
<?php echo $selstr ?>><?php echo $caption ?><
```

Check the >>< part

Answer (score 0):

<strike>According to http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.expressions.php , the semicolon terminates an expression (as opposed to seperating two expressions). I would guess maybe that in code like `<?php echo $val ?>`, must there not be a semicolon to make it 100% conforming?</strike>

Self-correction: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php

> The closing tag of a block of PHP code
>   automatically implies a semicolon

Answer (score 0):

To make your code more readable, think about using the [alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php):

```
<?php foreach(array("male","female") as $val): ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $val ?>" <?php echo ($row["Sex"] == $val)?'selected="selected"' : '' ?> > <?php echo $val ?> </option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I my opinion this way it is easier to see the structure of the code.

Comment: This doesn't really change much: `: ... end` is really no different to `{ ... }`. The important part to take from this answer, whichever way you choose, is to indent the PHP and HTML consistently.

Comment: @bobince: I no that it doesn't change much, but when you e.g. nested control structures, I guess one can get really confused by all the `<?php } ?>` because it is not necessarily clear where it belongs to. I just wanted to point out that one you check his code easier for errors if it is more readable.